# Applying background color to an empty div

Tags: html, css

I just started working on a new website, and I'm just trying to map out where everything will go. I made a few divs of the stuff I want.  When trying to add the background color to them in CSS it doesn't apply the color.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="hero"></div>
    <div class="ads"></div>
    <div class="content-1"></div>
    <div class="content-2"></div>
    <div class="form"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #7fffd4ad;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the height to be in pixels or rems rather than in a percentage(%). Percentages are based on the value of the parent element (which is currently 0).

```
.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20vh; // or 20px, 1em, 1rem ...
 background-color: #7fffd4ad;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The height need a value.. 20% of what ?
Try height: 30px to see.

Maybe you can try:   height: 20vh; too.

Will do what you want: 20%

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: #7fffd4ad;
}
```

Comment: ohhhh, thank you, I did vh before in another project, I forgot that its not the same as width

Comment: @Zombie_Slayer_19, if my answer helped you, you can accept the answer.
Maybe can help another person in the future.
See ya.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh; 
    background-color: #7fffd4ad;
}
```

Viewport Height (vh). This unit is based on the height of the viewport. A value of 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport height.

you can visit it to get more details : [Css Viewport Units](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/)